# Flyway is not creating the table but inserting the data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, flyway

Flyway is not creating the table but inserting the data.

I am trying to create a table and insert data through flyway in spring boot application.

These are in my resource/db/migration folder.

V1__Create_Hello.sql

```
CREATE TABLE hello (
        id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
        app VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        key VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        value TEXT,
        UNIQUE KEY unique_property (app, key)
);
```

I have another table called property where data insertion is happening perfectly. This table I have created manually

V2_Insert_properties.sql

`INSERT INTO property (app,key, value) VALUES ('app', ‘key1’, ‘va’l1);`

this is my `flyway_schema_history`

[image]

What can be the issue ?

Here is my application yml.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: config-server
  profiles:
    active: jdbc
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    url: "${MYSQL_URL:jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/myDB}”
    username: "${MYSQL_USERNAME:root}"
    password: "${MYSQL_PASSWORD:root}"
  flyway:
      enabled: true
      baseline-on-migrate: true
      locations: "classpath:db/migration"
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        jdbc:
          sql: SELECT property_key, property_value FROM property WHERE application = ? and profile = ? and label = ?
          order : 1
        encrypt:
          enabled: true
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
server:
  port: 8088

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: "*"
```

Comment: What output does Flyway give when you run it?

Comment: @Jorn I am not getting any error.. even when I am trying to keep only `V1__Create_Hello.sql` no error. table is not getting created

Comment: If configured correctly, Flyway will tell you what the current schema version is and that it didn't need to do anything. If you're not getting any output at all, that suggests Flyway didn't run. Check the code that calls it.

Comment: @Jorn only `flyway_schema_history` table is getting created. which code I need to see. I am just doing configuration in `pom.xml` and `application.yml`. any code need to be done form my side to run flyway ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flyway V1 is meaning init, so V1__Create_Hello.sql is create as init. so it shows as baseline. Change file name to V2 or others.

And it should be noted that 3.2 of 3.10 or 3.2 runs first because the version is recognized as an integer.

https://documentation.red-gate.com/fd/quickstart-how-flyway-works-184127223.html

[image]

Comment: Awesome. Thanks this is what I was missing. working fine now for me.